# Is it possible to create a BigQuery view in a SQL statement?

Tags: google-bigquery

For example, something like this in Postgres:

```
CREATE VIEW whatever AS
select *
from some_table
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot create view in a SQL statement (at least in its current dialect - who knows what will be introduced in current GCP NEXT)

See more on how to create View in BigQuery https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/querying-data#views